# Get memory address of overloaded operator?

Tags: c++

An extract of the header file of MyString class.

```
class MyString
{
...
public:
    bool IsEmpty(void) const;
    bool operator==(MyString const &)const;
    bool operator==(char const *)const;
...
};
```

Now i call a method of MyString in assembler, it works perfectly.

```
__declspec(naked)
void Injected() {
    __asm {
        //setup Call Parameters
        //...
        call MyString::IsEmpty  //bool IsEmpty(void) const;
    }
}
```

What worked for the method does not work for the operator.
Is it possible to get the address of a overloaded operator and call it in assembler?

```
__declspec(naked)
void Injected() {
    __asm {
        //setup Call Parameters
        //...
        call MyString::operator==  //bool operator==(char const *)const;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you cast at point of call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdd5392d.aspx) "An __asm block can call only global C++ functions that are not overloaded."

One solution is to add a helper function that you can call from asm. Something like:

```
bool equalCharPtr(char const *str)const { return *this == str; }
```

Of course this is only for Visual C++. Other compilers may vary.